# Combobox ItemSource not binding with data from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a Combobox:

```
<ComboBox   Height="23" 
            Name="DriveSelection" Width="120"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FixedDrives}"
            DisplayMemberPath="fixedDrives"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DriveSelection_SelectionChanged}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Here code for ItemsSource:

```
private ObservableCollection<DriveInfo> fixedDrives;
public ObservableCollection<DriveInfo> FixedDrives
{
    get
    {
        if(fixedDrives==null)
        {
           var query =
                from driveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                //where driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed
                select driveInfo;
           fixedDrives= new ObservableCollection<DriveInfo>(query);
           return fixedDrives;
        }

        return fixedDrives;
    }
}
```

and here event handler:

```
private void DriveSelection_SelectionChanged()
{
    if (page.DriveSelection.IsEnabled)
    {
        this.UpdatePathManager();
    }
}
```

I checked similiar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242301/having-trouble-binding-viewmodel-to-combobox) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159681/combobox-binding-to-custom-viewmodel) and didnt find there any answers.

I know that ViewModel is bounded to View. Other binds to buttons etc are working.

**After Updates:**

```
private DriveInfo driveSelection;
public DriveInfo DriveSelection_SelectionChanged
{
    get
    {
        return driveSelection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == driveSelection) return;
        driveSelection = value; 
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UpdatePathManager()); //UpdatePatchmanager is my function and it exists.
        //Notify... throws does not exists in currenct context
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox  Height="23" 
           Name="DriveSelection" 
           Width="120" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FixedDrives}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DriveSelection_SelectionChanged}" 
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

and binding the ViewModel:

```
public PathSelectionPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new PathSelectionPageViewModel(this);
}
```

After all thouse updates Combobox is still without any options and its greyed out.

And `NotifyOfPropertyChange` is throwing `does not exists in current context`
and:

```
class PathSelectionPageViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigable, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: Are `DriveSelection_SelectionChanged` and `FixedDrives` properties of `PathSelectionPageViewModel` class? Also `NotifyOfPropertyChange` should be called with property name so `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DriveSelection_SelectionChanged)` which should solve _does not exists in current context_ problem

Comment: Yes. Both of them are in `PathSelectionPageViewModel` class. Changing the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` doesnt change anything. Still it says that NotifyOfPropertyChange does not exist in current context

Answer (score 1):

Your `DisplayMemberPath` should be a property name within your `DriveInfo` class and not `DisplayMemberPath="fixedDrives"` and `SelectedItem` should be a property on VM of type `DriveInfo` not a function

Answer (score 1):

Your [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Should be a property of your Collection not the Collection Itself.

From this to:

```
 DisplayMemberPath="fixedDrives"
```

Something Like this:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" 
        Name="DriveSelection" Width="120"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FixedDrives}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Property1"
        SelectedItem="Property"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Comment: Ok I checked that FixedDrives[0] has property `Name` so I checked `DisplayMemberPath` to `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` and its still empty

Comment: @szpic Post your ViewModel where you bind data!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need write event handler because it is nor MVVM way. You must write something like this

```
   <ComboBox Height="23" 
        Name="DriveSelection" Width="120"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FixedDrives}"
        DisplayMemberPath="PropertyOfDriveInfo"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedInfo}" />

class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DriveInfo> fixedDrives;
    public ObservableCollection<DriveInfo> FixedDrives
    {
        get
        {
            if(fixedDrives==null)
            {
               var query =
                from driveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                //where driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed
                select driveInfo;
               fixedDrives= new ObservableCollection<DriveInfo>(query);
               return fixedDrives;
            }
            return fixedDrives;
         }
    }

    private DriveInfo _selectedInfo
    public DriveInfo SelectedInfo
    {
        get { return _electedInfo; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _electedInfo) return;
            _selectedInfo= value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedInfo);//must be implemented
        }
    }
}
```